# What does an $n$-body system with constant $T$ and $U$ look like?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

Can someone give an example of a system where the kinetic $T$ and potential $U$ energy are constant (but not zero)?

Here's what I have in mind: Say you have $n-1$ satellites of negligible mass sharing the same eccentric elliptical orbit around a star (the $n^{th}$ body), and say that these satellites are always positioned and have velocity such that $\nabla U=0$ at all times in the orbit.

(As usual in such a case, $U\sim -\sum^n_i \frac{1}{r_i}$ where $r_i$ is the distance of the $i^{th}$ satellite from the star.)

This would mean that $U$ remains constant throughout the orbit, but that (given the eccentricity of the orbit) the $r_i$'s of each of the satellites are always changing.  Since total energy is conserved, the very fact that $U$ is constant means that $T$ must also be constant even though all of the velocities of the individual satellites are always changing.  So this hypothetical system would be one in which $T$ and $U$ are constant, right?

Comment: Any object that can have $T$ and $U$ energy = 0 can be defined to have any value ($T = 10$ and $U = 20$).  This is like changing coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermally supported, self-gravitating bodies (those to which the Virial theorem applies) qualify if you are willing to neglect the radiative energy loss.

Depending on the time-scales that interest you this can be quite a good approximation. Stellar nebulae, brown dwarfs and so on.